# Soundclound api - don't download whole JSON

Tags: soundcloud

imagine situation I have track ID and I want to get a list of all favoriters. That's easy, I just need to send /tracks/{id}/favoriters request and I get list of users with full info.

But is it somehow possible to specify that I just need the ID's of the users, not whole structure? Or just names of the users?

thanks, Jano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no, this isn't possible. There are no ways to dictate the types of object that are returned from the API, in your case I imagine being able to return a `MiniUser` instead of a `User` representation would be more helpful.